# Vue2/Nuxt- How to keep v-menu's content always in place when opening on-hover?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

First off apologies if this ends up being a duplicate, but I haven't found anything else on SO that meets my current problem. Also, this is my first time working with either Vue or Nuxt, so bear with me if I am a bit green with the framework.

I am working on an app using Vue 2 (v. 2.6.14), Vuetify (@nuxtjs/vuetify v. 1.12.3) and Nuxt (v 2.15.8), where my main locale file (where pretty much all of the app's content lives) has a v-app-bar to act as my header. Inside said v-app-bar I have a dropdown menu whose html content is this:

```
<v-app-bar :clipped-left="false" fixed app elevation="0" color="neutral-300" height="80">
  <div>
    <v-menu open-on-hover bottom offset-y>
      <template #activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-btn depressed color="neutral-300" v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
          <span class="text-b2  neutral-800--text text-capitalize">{{ user }}</span>
          <v-btn icon>
            <v-icon color="black">
              mdi-menu-down
            </v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </v-btn>
      </template>

      <v-list class="py-0" id="logout">
        <v-list-item link>
          <v-list-item-title @click="logout">
            {{ $t('COMMON.LOG_OUT') }}
          </v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-menu>
  </div>
</v-app-bar>
```

The {{ user }} variable that the span inside the v-btn renders comes from a computed variable that the app will always have access to in the context of my layout, since its `auth` variable is set to true;

```
  computed: {
    user() {
      return `${this.$auth.user.firstname} ${this.$auth.user.lastname}`;
    },
 },
```

On hover, and if the app works uninterrupted and unrefreshed, the dropdown behavior on hover is as expected:
[image: correct-behavior]

BUT, if the app reloads during the `npm run dev` live reload or if I refresh the app manually (F5/ Cmd+R), the dropdown displays this behavior (appears on the left side, ignores the offset-y property), and the only way to revert it back to its expected behavior is to log out of the app and log back in:

[image]

I have been able to force the dropdown to stay in the desired place using the following scss bit in the  area of my Vue component and it does the trick, but it feels very hacky:

```
.v-menu {
  min-width: 300px;
}

.v-menu__content {
  left: auto !important;
  right: 16px !important;
  top: 58px !important;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea on what might be causing the menu to behave in this way?

Comment: maybe try to add `position: relative` to the parent element of the logout button. The issue occurs because the element overlap its parents. to prevent this kind of issue. we must add somewhere a relative position to the parent.